# roslaunch and ports

Tags: roslaunch, roscore, rostopic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I may be missing something, but if it's possible to start roslaunch (roscore) on a [specific port](http://www.ros.org/wiki/roslaunch/Commandline%20Tools).. shouldn't it be possible/necessary to pass a port to tools like rostopic so they can communicate with the "right" ros graph?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/46842/roslaunch-and-ports/) by [SL Remy](https://answers.ros.org/users/1001/sl-remy/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2022 on 2012-10-26

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

That's what ROS_MASTER_URI is for. You can start roscore on a different port with the `--port` parameter, e.g.:

```
roscore --port=11411
```

Then set the ROS_MASTER_URI to the new URI:

```
export ROS_MASTER_URI=http://localhost:11411
```

Now, all ros nodes should contact the core on port 11411. That way, you can run several ros cores on the same machine.

---

Originally posted by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) with karma: 22731 on 2012-10-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [SL Remy](https://answers.ros.org/users/1001/sl-remy/) on 2012-10-26**:
Ah yes.. thanks.. not sure why I forgot about the env var.. but this is how I'd use it (for reference) ROS_MASTER_URI=http://localhost:11411 rostopic list